# Attempting to deploy static site (PHP) in Heroku shows source code instead?

Tags: php, .htaccess, heroku

I followed the steps documented [here](http://kennethreitz.org/static-sites-on-heroku-cedar/)

I added `php_flag engine off` to my `.htaccess` file, turned my `index.html` file to `index.php`, however my Heroku app shows me source code? You can see this happening [here](http://cakecakecake.heroku.com)

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

Comment: uh, so you turn PHP off, then ask why php isn't working?

Comment: From the first link: "When you push this up, you’ll have a bare Apache instance serving up the contents of your site to the world."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just upload it intact, don't do the .htaccess change.